# Dual basis derivatives and affine connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to prove that:

$\partial_{c} \vec{e^{a}} = - \Gamma_{bc}^{a} \vec{e^{b}}$

Where $\vec{e^{i}}$ represents one of the vectors from a basis of a dual vector space. To do the proof, I'm doing that:

I know that the affine connection can be defined as:

$\frac{\partial \vec{e_{a}}}{\partial x^{c}} = \Gamma_{ac}^{b} \vec{e_{b}} $

So I start with this and do a dot product with a vector from the dual basis, and with that I have:

$ \vec{e^{d}} \cdot \partial_{c} \vec{e_{a}} = \Gamma_{ac}^{b} \vec{e^{d}} \cdot \vec{e_{b}} = \Gamma_{ac}^{b} \delta_{b}^{d}$

where I used the reciprocal relation $\vec{e^{d}} \cdot \vec{e_{b}} = \delta_{b}^{d}$. And so, the equation turns out to be:

$ \vec{e^{d}} \cdot \partial_{c} \vec{e_{a}} = \Gamma_{ac}^{d}$
 or

$\Gamma_{ac}^{b} = \vec{e^{b}} \cdot \partial_{c} \vec{e_{a}}$

as **b** and **d** represents just dummie indices. To continue with my proof I differentiated the reciprocal relation with respect to the coordinate $x^{c}$, to find that:

$\partial_{c}(\vec{e^{b}}\cdot\vec{e_{a}}) = (\partial_{c}\vec{e^{b}})\cdot\vec{e_{a}}+\vec{e^{b}}\cdot(\partial_{c}\vec{e_{a}}) = 0 $

Now using that, we can write:

$\Gamma_{ac}^{b} = -(\partial_{c}\vec{e^{b}})\cdot\vec{e_{a}}$

**So, how can I go from that to the formula I want to prove?**
I imagined to do another dot product with a vector from the dual basis but I didn't work out.

Comment: You are done, aren't you? Just substitute in your last equation, the expression of $\partial_c\vec v^b$ in terms of the Christoffel symbols for the fuel connection, say $\Gamma^*$.

Comment: Just a pedantic comment. $\partial/\partial x^c$ doesn't make sense. It really is $\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^c}$ that you're defining here, where $\nabla$ is the connection. Some classical tensor analysis books write this as a subscript "$;c$."

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought the same and I don't think it's pedantic but useful, because the nabla notation is the standard notation nowadays. I think it can help other users (or even the OP) to clarify things.

Comment: @Dog_69 Nah, I could'd get it, could you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: @TedShifrin, sorry. It seems that I'm not using an updated book to study

Comment: @llgsi Simply define coefficients $\Lambda_{ab}^c$ by the relation $\nabla_a e^c=\Lambda_{ab}^c e^b$ and put it in your last expression. Then you will get the desired result.

Comment: Actually you are done bcause $e_a$ and $e^b$ are dual basis, your last expression actually means that $\nabla_ae^c=-\Gamma_{ab}^c e^b$, you don't need to define the coefficients $\Lambda_{ab}^c$. However, they may help you if you don't see this directly.